# char has only the last pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I'm putting all file names (in this case all files in the folder /Windows/Fonts/) into the char File_Names. Menawhile the names are rendered as well, but after I have put everything in the char (when while ends), I try to access it and use one of the names in something else (this happens after while), but every single pointer I try only gives the last file from the folder (this means, it only has the last pointer). How do I keep all different file names and can use them after while?
Here is a fragment from my program:

```
//-------------------- List files start
                  int File_Name_Y =  Font_Window_Y+35-Mouse_Scroll*10;
                  char *File_Names[4096];
                  struct dirent *entry;
                  DIR *dir = opendir("/Windows/Fonts");
                  int t = 1;
                  while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
                    {
                      t += 1;
                      File_Names[t] = entry->d_name;
                      if (File_Name_Y <= Font_Window_Y+H-65 && File_Name_Y >= Font_Window_Y+30)
                        {
                          draw_text (Font_Window_X+15, File_Name_Y, File_Names[t], {1, 1, 1}, 1.5);
                        }
                      File_Name_Y += 20;
                    }
                  closedir(dir);
                  //------------------ List files end

                  if (use_button (SelectFontButton))
                    {
                      if (Mouse_Pressed)
                        {
                          Mouse_Pressed = 0;
                          char Font_Path[1024];
                          strcpy (Font_Path, "/Windows/Fonts/");
                          strcat(Font_Path, File_Names[3]);
                          strcpy (Global_Font, Font_Path);
                          printf (Global_Font);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the exact same value, `entry->d_name` in every entry. Of course they're all going to point to the same string.

You may be thinking that `readdir` *changes* the value of `entry->d_name` to something different every time. But it doesn't. Every time, it sets the value of `entry->d_name` to point to the very same buffer that `readdir` uses to hold the entry name.

You need to save the actual name, not a pointer to a buffer controlled by some other piece of code. Allocating an array of pointers is insufficient -- where are the actual entry names going to be stored?

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you mind clarifying your last paragraph, please?

Comment: @PhilipAvramov If you want to save every name, you need to actually allocate space for each name and copy the name into the space you allocated. But all your code does is allocate a bunch of pointers with nothing for those pointers to point to. (Where does your code allocate memory to save the names in? Your only `malloc` call only allocates pointers which only hold pointers to other things. You never allocate anything for those pointers to point to.)

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you.